# How can I properly set up label and textbox padding?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I cannot get the format I want with my labels and textboxes. My end goal is to have it look like the attached picture where I can set the margin/padding/offset for the labels and then set a different margin/padding/offset for the textboxes?

[image: I want it to look like this]

```css
.lblright {
  float: right;
  width: 120px;
  padding-right: 500px;
}

.lblleft {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.lblleft2 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  padding-left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<asp:Label ID="lblInputAccountHtml" runat="server" Text="Account" class="lblleft"></asp:Label>
<input type="text" ID="tbxInputAccount[![enter image description here][1]][1]Html" runat="server" style="width: 125px;" class="lblleft2">
<br>
<asp:Label ID="lblInputNameAssignedHtml" runat="server" Text="Name Assigned" class="lblleft"></asp:Label>
<input type="text" id="tbxInputNameAssignedHtml" runat="server" style="width: 125px;" class="lblright">
<br>
<asp:Label ID="lblInputEmailAddressHtml" runat="server" Text="Email Address" class="lblleft"></asp:Label>
<input type="text" id="tbxInputEmailAddressHtml" runat="server" style="width: 125px;" class="lblright">
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. I changed your code and used simple html. Hope this helps.

```css
.inputContainer {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.inputContainer label {
  width: 200px;
}
.inputContainer input {
  width: 125px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputContainer">
    <label for="tbxInputAccount" id="lblInputAccountHtml">Account</label>
    <input type="text" ID="tbxInputAccount" />
</div>
<div class="inputContainer">
    <label for="tbxInputNameAssignedHtml" id="lblInputNameAssignedHtml" >Name Assigned</label>
    <input type="text" id="tbxInputNameAssignedHtml"/>
</div>
<div class="inputContainer">
    <label id="lblInputEmailAddressHtml">Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="tbxInputEmailAddressHtml"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to tweak the answer from @negool because it had a JS error and didn't display properly, but it got me close enough. This is what works

```
   <div class="inputContainer">
        <asp:Label ID="lblInputAccountHtml" runat="server" Text="Account"></asp:Label>
        <input type="text" ID="tbxInputAccountHtml" /> 
    </div>
    <div class="inputContainer">
        <asp:Label ID="lblInputNameAssignedHtml" runat="server" Text="Name Assigned"></asp:Label>
        <input type="text" id="tbxInputNameAssignedHtml" />
    </div>
    <div class="inputContainer">
        <asp:Label ID="lblInputEmailAddressHtml" runat="server" Text="Email Address asdfasdfasdfasdf"></asp:Label>
        <input type="text" id="tbxInputEmailAddressHtml" />
    </div>


<style type="text/css">

    .inputContainer {
      width: 550px;
      padding: 5px;
      padding-left: 75px;
    }

    .inputContainer label {
      width: 275px;
    }
    .inputContainer input {
      width: 225px;
      float: right;
    }
```